# Tekla Structures API Plugin With Python

Tags: python, c#

Tekla Structures Open API plugins are based on C# .Net. Is it possible to write the plugins with python and then convert and get the same class library DLL file to be loaded into Tekla software?
As another question, please let me know your idea on which one to use, C# or python, since I am new to this field.

Thanks